# Load related entity's from jump table

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I have a jump table to relate the Customers and the contact, I want to load all contacts by a customer name. What is the best way to do that?

```
   Dim Q = From Cust In EnData.Customers Where Cust.CustomerID = ID Select Cust
            ContactRow = Q.FirstOrDefault.CustomerToContacts.??? here I'm stock...
```

[image: table layout]

Comment: Is the relationship between `Customer` and `Contact` many-to-many?

Comment: Yes they are. (As seen in the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
var customerContacts = EnData.CustomerToContact
                           .Where(c => c.Customer.CustName.Equals(custName))
                           .Select(c => c.Contact);
```

This should return an `IQueryable<Contact>` containing all of the contacts for the customer with the provided `custName`. You'll have to convert it to VB as this is in C#, although I assume that should be rather straight forward.